# Python automatic connection in local network call for WinError 10061

Tags: python, sockets, lan

I'm trying to make a program which can automatically connect to a computer in the local network based on the port inputted by the server. then the client, with the same port, tries by using the arp -a command to find every computer in the local network and try to connect to him.

This is the connection Method:

```
def connect(self):
    devices = []
    for device in os.popen('arp -a'): devices.append(device)
    for ip in devices:
        b = re.findall(r"(?:\s|\A)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=\s|\Z)", ip)
        try:
            print(b[0])
            client_socket = socket.socket()
            client_socket.settimeout(3)
            client_socket.connect((b[0], self.port))
            if type(client_socket) != None:
                return client_socket
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I get a pretty weird issue: when I try to be a server on one computer, it works out just fine. However, when I try to switch the roles and be the client on that computer, it suddenly cant find the target computer and when it tries its IP (which I know since I checked the IP address of the computer with ipconfig), it errors out:

```
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
timed out
```

I'm trying this on 2 different computers and it connects perfectly when i try this with this computer as server. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Also, I thought it would be helpful to note that no matter how high i set the timeout to be on the socket, it just waits that amount of time with the correct IP, then says it timed out. This is despite the server binding the port already...

Edit 2.0: Thought about looking at connection errors of the connection program at the other computer... completely different. no 10061 errors, just timing out and list index errors which are perfectly understandable with the nature of the function. Why does it only does the 10061 error on one computer? why when its 2 different computers? I'd like to know.

Comment: Most likely different firewall settings

Comment: Sorry... Tried to completely disable firewall and run it... didn't work.